# How to implement tinymce with django for client side?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I did lot of research on how to implement django tinymce for users and not for admin but I got no real answer.
Is there any way to do it.
Any help would be highly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use tiny mce as a default widget in django forms for text django-tinymce is probably what you are looking for.

https://django-tinymce.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the documentation and once you have configured it you can define it as a widget in your forms as the following:

```py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.flatpages.models import FlatPage
from tinymce.widgets import TinyMCE

class FlatPageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    content = forms.CharField(widget=TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 30}))
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = FlatPage
```

Checkout the official documentation for settings: [here](https://django-tinymce.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)